# Extremely low Admob Impressions

Tags: android, admob, ads, banner

I developed a new application some time ago and implemented Google Ads directly on it. It worked perfectly at first, and once I published it on the Play Store, it still worked well. But, for maybe a month now there have been no more impressions, something like 1 impression per 1000 requests or even less. I really don't understand why. All I know is that it used to work and it stopped working for no reason, and one of my other applications is now working perfectly when it really makes fewer requests. 
I've been trying different solutions and contacting Google for almost a month now, but nothing really seems to help me. I even recreated my ads, but it didn't help.

Maybe I can say that this problem occurred when I decided to link the Play Store application to Admob. But again, I'm not sure.

Do you have any final advice for me? Because I'm really lost, nothing I've seen on Stackoverflow or any other forum has helped me so far.

Thank you for your help,

Sincerely,

Florian

Answer (score 0):

i have the same issue here 2 days ago, suddenly impressions to low compared to the requests and the ads don't show on the apps, i think they made this change while your AdMob account in not verified yet with verification PIN.

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Comment: nop, still waiting for the verification Pin to arrive, i don't now this cause that low rate, but at the meantime no earning, a high request impression and the ads still not showing